# sudoers sudoedit recursive wildcard

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I want to allow editing any file (recursively) under specific directory via sudoers.

None of the below works (Debian 9 sudo)

```
ops ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /opt/myapps/
ops ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /opt/myapps/*
ops ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /opt/myapps/**
ops ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /opt/myapps/**/*
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Not sure you can do that. The command is run 'as is'. Anyway, once you are inside the editor, I don't know what would stop the user to open another file. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani - want to let a support user edit config files in a non-sensitive area without changing permissions on those files (as it would require changing the installation process of tons of software)

Answer (score 0):

You could give the user access to the sudo group:

Here's how I setup a non-root user on Ubuntu 18.04:

```bsh
groupadd -g 999 foobaz && useradd -u 999 -g foobaz -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foobaz &&
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' &&
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' &&
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' &&
echo "foobaz ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers &&
echo "Enabled passwordless access to the sudo group for the foobaz user!" &&
echo "foobaz user:";  su - foobaz -c id
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foobaz` is created.
- The user `foobaz` is added to the both the `foobaz` and `sudo` group.
- The `uid` and `gid` is set to the value of `999`.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foobaz`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foobaz` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

Then you'll be able to run `su foobaz`, `sudo -s`, `exit`, etc.

---

If you want the short version, just run:

```bsh
echo "foobaz ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Beware that this will append to the existing `/etc/sudoers` file instead of properly updating the contents.